# Python fast way to substitute specific values in array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, filter, substitution

Say I have two numpy arrays

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
b = np.array([2,7,6])
```

and I want to obtain

```
c = np.array([[1,0,3],[4,5,0][0,8,9]])
```

that is, I want to substitute with value `0` all the elements in array `a` whose value is contained in sequence `b`.
Fastest and cleanest way to do it?
(Is there something like `substitute(a,b,0)`)

Comment: I didn't try. The only way that comes up in my mind is looping. I am wondering if there is a vectorized way to do it. `np.select`, `np.choice`, `np.place` ... are all based on conditionals or masks as far as I know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternate answer:

```
c = a.copy()
c[np.in1d(a.ravel(), b).reshape(a.shape)] = 0
```

`np.in1d` is kind of a like a vectorized version of the "in" operator, but it only works for 1D arrays. (Hence the ravel and reshape operations.)

Answer (score 1):

```
c = a.copy()
for num in b:
    c[c == num] = 0
```

Comment: `c[c == num]` pretty way of ofuscating things....

Comment: How is that obfuscating? The values of `c` that are equal to `num` need to be set to zero, where `num` takes on each value in `b`.

Comment: @DanielSanchez numpy arrays support rich indexing like [boolean indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing). That is an idiomatic pattern.

Comment: interesting, but still too ofuscating for me, anyhow I removed the downvote, sorry.